# Converting infix-expression to postfix-expression causing weird symbols to show up

Tags: c, stack, binary-tree

I am trying to parse a **fully parenthesized infix-expression** and convert it to a **postfix-expression** so I can easily implement the expression into a binary arithmetic tree.

Here is an example string that I am using: ***((x2+5.14)*(3.41-5.00))***

Here is the output: [image]

I am trying to print out the postfix-expression of the command line infix-expression.
I am almost positive there are memory leaks in here, but I cannot pinpoint exactly where things are going wrong. Could someone point out my (many) mistakes?

```
char *infixToPrefix(char *argString)
{
    int i,j;
    int popLoop = 1;
    int length = strlen(argString);
    char tempChar;
    char tempString[5];
    char *returnString = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
    Stack *opStack = createStack(length-1);

    for(i=0;i<length-1;i++)
    {
        char *tempPop = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
        /* Character is a number; we assume a floating point in the form Y.XZ */
        if(isdigit(argString[i]) > 0)
        {
            /* Take argString[i] and next three characters */
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                tempString[j] = argString[i];
                i++;
            }           
            i--;
            tempString[4] = ' ';        
            returnString = strcat(returnString, tempString);

            /* Recycle tempString by assigning first character to null pointer */
            tempString[0] = '\0';
        }

        /* Character is variable; we assume the format is xY, where Y is an integer from 0-9 */
        else if(argString[i] == 'x')
        {   
            for(j=0; j<2; j++)
            {
                tempString[j] = argString[i];
                i++;
            }
            i--;            
            tempString[2] = ' ';
            returnString = strcat(returnString, tempString);

            /* Recycle */
            tempString[0] = '\0';
        }

        /* Character is binary operator; push on top of Operator Stack */
        else if(argString[i] == '*' || argString[i] == '/' ||
                argString[i] == '+' || argString[i] == '-')
        {
            tempString[0] = argString[i];
            tempString[1] = '\0';
            push(opStack,tempString);
            tempString[0] = '\0';
        }

        /* Character is open parenthesis; push in top of Operator Stack */
        else if(argString[i] == '(')
        {
            tempString[0] = argString[i];
            tempString[1] = '\0';
            push(opStack,tempString);
            tempString[0] = '\0';
        }

        /* Character is closed parenthesis; pop Operator Stack until open parenthesis is popped */
        else if(argString[i] == ')')
        {   
            while(popLoop)
            {
                tempPop = pop(opStack);
                tempChar = tempPop[0];
                if(tempChar == '(')
                {
                    free(tempPop);
                    popLoop = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    returnString = strcat(returnString, tempPop);
                    free(tempPop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    returnString = strcat(returnString, "\0");
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Note; When codes does `Take argString[i] and next three characters`, nothing prevents `i` going past the end of the string.  Similar for `argString[i] == 'x'`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char)*length);` should be `malloc(length+1);`

Comment: `strcat(returnString, "\0");` does not append anything.

Comment: What's the best way to add a null terminator to the end of a string?

Comment: @destroted: the simplest way is to make sure the string has been cleared before you start, by using calloc instead of malloc. Otherwise you need to track the current end of the string and set that value to 0. (strcat doesn't help you much here. But strcat is awful. Don't use it.) Note that all of the string functions assume that the string is NUL-terminated and ensure that the result is as well, so you usually only need to explicitly nul-terminate the initial value and after low-level manipulations.

Comment: @rici Minor nit if you care: "make sure the string has been cleared" should be "make sure the `char` array has been cleared" as _string_, by C definition, all ready has a `'\0'` termination,

Answer (score 2):

Various problems

1. Insufficient memory allocation

   ```
   // char *returnString = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
   char *returnString = malloc(length+1);
   ```
2. Failure to append `'\0'`.
   `strcat(returnString, "\0");` is the same as `strcat(returnString, "");`.  IAC, code cannot call string functions on `returnString` as it does not yet have a null character termination and is therefore not a string.

   ```
   // returnString = strcat(returnString, "\0");
   returnString[i] = '\0';
   ```
3. In 2 places, code does not protect against running off the end of the string.

   ```
   // for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
   for(j=0; argString[i]!='\0' && j<4; j++) {
     tempString[j] = argString[i];
     i++;
   }    
   // tempString[4] = ' ';     
   tempString[j] = '\0';
   ```
4. Usage of `tempPop` is dubious in `tempPop = pop(opStack);`. Why did code even allocate it further up?
5. Maybe others and with `stack` is not declared, can't go much further.